# Using back-propagation to approximate a function and then find its maximum?

Tags: neural-network, mathematical-optimization, backpropagation

I have an unknown function, say, F(x), which I use a back-propagation neural network to approximate.  Surely this can be done, as it is in the standard repertoire of neural networks.

F(x) does not explicitly exist.  It is learned from a training set of data points.

Say, the NN learns a function G(x) which approximates F(x).

AFTER the learning of G is finished, I want to find the  global maximum value of G(x), and the position of x when that occurs.

Given that G is implicitly realized by the NN, I don't have the explicit form of G.

Is there any quick algorithm that allows me to find arg-max(x) of G(x) ?

Comment: Can you give an example of one such function you can approximate and training data sets ?

Comment: Just to make sure I understood you: You have a list of x's and a corresponding list of the values of F(x) at these points, and you want to find the local/global maxima of F(x). Am I correct?

Comment: @ZachiShtain that is OPs  training set and not what he is trying to evaluate. Neural network is a classifier from which you cannot extract implicit function it generated.

Comment: Yes, I want to find the global maximum of the *learned* function G(x) which is an approximation of F(x).  F(x) don't explicitly exist.

Comment: Question edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neural networks would give rise to discontinuous functions (in general) since it consists of a network of discontinuous functions (a neuron fires at a certain threshold which is a jump discontinuity). But -- if in you application it makes sense to think of G(x) as (approximately) continuous or even differentiable, you could use hill-climbing techniques where you start at a random point, estimate the derivative (or gradient if `x` is a vector rather than a scalar) and move in the direction of steepest increase a short step, repeating the process until no more improvement is found. This gives you an approximate local maximum. You can repeat the process with different randomly starting values. If you always get the same result then you can be reasonably confident (though not certain) that it is in fact a global max.

Without any assumptions on `G(x)` it is hard to say anything definite. If `x` is chosen randomly then `G(x)` is a random variable. You can use statistical methods to estimate e.g. its 99th percentile. You could also try using an evolutionary algorithm in which `G(x)` plays the role of a fitness function.

Comment: If the individual neurons have sigmoid threshold functions, doesn't that make the resulting G(x) continuous and differentiable?

Comment: I was thinking of garden-variety neural nets where the elements either fire or they don't. If you have some version where the output is a differentiable function of the input, then, yes the overall function would be differentiable.

Comment: Could the structure of the NN be exploited so that I can find the maxima faster?

Comment: @YanKingYin Good question. I don't know, but I would imagine that the answer is in principle "yes". Having information about how a function is put together couldn't possibly hurt.

Comment: I'm trying the gradient descent method you suggested, but since the function G(x) is only implicitly known, the calculation of the gradient seems rather complicated.  It's a very long sum and product arising from the chain-rule.

Comment: I was thinking in terms of numerical differentiation. Maybe the symmetric difference quotient (which is often used for differentiation in graphing calculators)